# R for loop termination on out of bounds

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to do the following nested for loop structure in R:

```
x<- c(a,b,c,d,e)
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  for(j in (i+1):length(x)){
     do something with (x, j)
  }
}
```

However, what ends up happening is that at one point j=6 (because j goes from i+1), and the loop still tries to execute and causes an out of bounds.

Of course I can always put in an if statement to check that j <= length(x) before I run the command but is there a way to do this more elegantly?  For instance, in C++, I believe that the second loop would never execute...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: or just have i go from 1 to j - 1?

Comment: @rawr: you mean i go from 1 to length(x)-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for( j in seq(i + 1, length = length(x) - i) ) ...
```

or

```
for( j in i + seq_len(length(x) - i) ) ...
```

or

```
for( j in seq(i, length(x))[-1] ) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual advice is to use seq_along:

```
x<- c(a,b,c,d,e)
for(i in seq_along(x)){
  for(j in seq_along( x[ -(1:i) ] ){
     do something with (x, i, j)
  }
}
```